# \input in figure environment not centering

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, floats, subfloats

I'm making a presentation with beamer, and I've drawn some figures in TikZ that I'm inserting into the presentation using `\input{footikz.tex}`

For some reason the tikz picture is appearing off to the right of where they should be.  Below is some of my code, I was wondering if anyone could spot a silly mistake I'm making?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsubsection}
\begin{alertblock}{\insertsubsubsection}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
{\scalebox{0.4}{\input{Figures/Tikz/Arrows0.tex}}}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
{\scalebox{0.4}{\input{Figures/Tikz/Arrows180.tex}}}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.2\textwidth}
{\scalebox{0.4}{\input{Figures/Tikz/Arrows360.tex}}}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}

\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
```

In this instance, the first subfigure appears in the center of the page and the next two are placed to the right of it.  I'd like them to be left, center, right.

Later in the presentation I have an extremely similar layout and it works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please make your code fully compilable, meaning starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `...\end{document}`? Also please include code from your other files in your post, otherwise the solvers are wildly guessing what's going on in the code.

Comment: Replace the \input command with the contents of the file and see if it still happens?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always post complete code in future.

This is an alternative. Since you are not using separate captions (which are not needed for a presentation IMO), you need not use `subcaption` package. Simple `minipage` will do. Further, if you can save your pictures as `.tikz` files (I hope you use `tikz` for those pictures, if not I will discard this answer), you can use `tikzscale` package and then the `tikz` files can be included using the regular `\includegraphics` command with all the keys like `width`, `height` etc available.

A sample code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {Here};
    \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test2.tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {Here};
    \draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test3.tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {Here};
    \draw (0,0) circle (4cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsubsection}
\begin{alertblock}{\insertsubsubsection}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test1.tikz}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test2.tikz}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test3.tikz}
\end{minipage}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]